# C++ call C function with C struct pointer parameter

Tags: c++

If I remember correctly. This code should work.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct {
        int a;
    } Base;

    typedef struct {
        int a;
    } Derived;

    void Init(Base* b) {
        b->a = 1;
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


int main() {
    Derived d;
    Init(&d); // error can not convert argument 1 from 'Derived *' to 'Base *'
}
```

It's compiles as C source(without extern "C"). How can I make it compile as C++ without modifying the C part?

Edit: I modified the code so that it can be actually copy and test in both C and C++.

Comment: you have not actually derived `Derived` from `Base`.

Comment: @RichardHodges That part is C source. Not C++.

Comment: @J.Doe So how should the compiler convert `Derived *` to `Base *` if they are not related?

Comment: @J.Doe So how do you plan to use inheritance without actually inheriting

Comment: `stdio.h` is a deprecated C-compatibility header - use `cstdio` and friends instead.

Comment: @Darhuuk Gaurav Sehgal. So you mean I have to re declare everything the C++ way and pray they are binary compatible with the original C. I don't remember been teached that way before.

Comment: `extern "C"` makes no difference to struct definitions, only to functions. You do have to rely on your compiler suite using the same layout for structs in both languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiles in C (while generating a warning) because type abuse is more accepted in the C world. It is common for compilers to allow transgressions of the standard.

In C++ you'll need to `reinterpret_cast` the pointer:

```
Init(reinterpret_cast<Base*>(&d));
```

or

```
Init((Base*)&d);
```

Ideally you'll want to encapsulate this pointer abuse into the smallest maintainable suite of functions or classes you can.

Comment: The relevant code is an error in both C and C++, this "type abuse" is not permissible in either language. The words used to report an error are up to the choice of the people writing the compiler

Comment: Not sure what you think that link is trying to illustrate; the authors of gcc decided to use the word "warning" when reporting this error

Comment: @M.M the fact that gcc compiles it in C with a warning, rather than failing with an error as it does in C++.

Comment: You're commenting on gcc's behaviour (under certain switches or lack of them), not the C language

Comment: Richard, "warning" or "error" is still up to the implementer. The C standard requires a diagnostic. And `Wpedantic` does just that on standard violations. It's not okay to abuse types like this in C either.

Comment: @M.M Hmm. What am I really trying to say... Probably that the reality of C is that it started out as effectively a semi-portable macro-assembler. Because of its history and very close ties to real computer systems (rather than the idealised memory model of modern c++), abuse is endemic in general C practice and therefore allowed by compilers. C programmers tend to be "experts" who understand how a computer works. They demand the ability to "abuse" because it's often the right/only way to get something done without resorting to `asm`.

Comment: I'm with you for the first half of that comment, but I'd say they "demand the ability to abuse" because it's what they are used to doing .  It's entirely possible to code without relying on this (In this case, using a cast operator), and old code can (in most cases, I'm sure there are a few exceptions) be ported to compile cleanly with strict compiler settings

Comment: @M.M fair comment. I'm one of those old die-hards who learned to code in assembler. Even I would have used a cast in this code - for clarity if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Derived` name is missleading. You aren't deriving `Derived` from `Base` and structural equivalence in C doesn't mean much. It could work with cast, but you will have to keep this equivalence without any help of the compiler. When some day you decide to change `Base` definition

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int c; /* New field */
} Base;
```

you will have to modify all *"derived"* definitions.

In C deriving is usually simulated by embedding:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct {
        int a;
    } Base;

    typedef struct {
        Base base;
    } Derived;

    void Init(Base* b) {
        b->a = 1;
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Init(&d.base);
}
```